# getAdapterPosition not working (v24)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, cardview

I am using on bind view holder though but for some reasons I am getting the 'cannot resolve method error".
As you can see this is my first attempt so I might be committing some huge mistake.
I have tried multiple methods but none of them seems to work.

```
package com.techhgeeks.techhgeeks;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import java.util.List;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;




public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context context;
    private List<MyData> my_data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_child,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.description.setText(my_data.get(position).getDescription());
        Glide.with(context).load(my_data.get(position).getImage_link()).into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

    }


    public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView description;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Where is "cannot resolve method error" being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem which is because that you are using the getAdapterPosition in the wrong place.

First, remove this part in the original code (onClick):

```
int position = getAdapterPosition();
```

Second, modify the onCreateViewHolder method.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_child, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: I am using  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.+'

Comment: Tried rebuilding, clean bulid ... same error " cannot resolve method getAdapterPosition" 
Are you sure there is nothing wrong with my code?

Comment: The getAdapterPosition method is in the ViewHolder class.

Comment: the Intent constructor is not working under this onClick method

Answer (score 1):

`getAdapterPosition()` are part of revision 22 of the support library. You are not able to resolve it because you are still using rev 21. Change

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

to

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
```

then build the project.

Comment: I am already using 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'